# Android: ListView in AlertDialog only shows one row

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a ListView inside a AlertDialog, the problem I am having is that ListView only shows one row, even there's multiple rows in the ListView. The AlertDialog doesn't seem to expand. How can I make it show as many rows as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Johnny

Comment: What code produces such AlertDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hiii Johnny

i see your question and then i tested for lot of demo finally i got the solution for that

here i can put link which is helpful to you and you can test them

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-display-alertdialog-and.html

Answer (score 0):

final CharSequence[] items = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
             // Do something...
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below post for listview inside a alert dialog:  [link](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/android-dialog-with-listview/)